# Query a component from an external script

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I'd like to instantiate a Joomla2.5 component (JoomShopping) and get some information from it via some of its methods. But I want to do this from another PHP application. I tried just including the main items from Joomla's index.php as follows below, but the JSFactory object is not instantiated. How do I activate this component so I can query it?

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
$app->route();
$app->dispatch();

$pm_method = JSFactory::getTable('paymentMethod', 'jshop');
$pmconfigs = $pm_method->getConfigs();
print_r($pmconfigs);
```

Comment: Maybe you could extend JoomShopping to have some url that output what you need in JSON and have the other app read this?

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer :-)

Just set $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to something that will cause the Joomla framework to route the request to the component you want. In my case setting the URI to '/Loja' caused the JoomShopping component to be installed so all its classes were present for me to query.